# Detect circular references between objects in .NET using Reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection, c++-cli

My program needs to determine whether an object graph contains circular references. The object graph contains object instances of various types (all descended from one base class) and, if well-formed, should form a hierarchy. A circular reference would cause an infinite loop during processing. I need to determine this before processing of the individual elements begins, to produce an appropriate error message.

The program is written in C++/CLI and targets .NET 3.5. I thought perhaps Reflection might offer some elegant way to accomplish this, but so far I haven't been able to put the pieces together.

In the event that a pre-made easy API doesn't exist, I could construct a stack and make up such a function myself; however since there are various classes involved, Reflection might play a part anyway. Or am I barking up the totally wrong tree?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in method to detect cycles using reflection. However, reflection seems unnecessary here.

From what you're saying, it sounds like the objects in this graph are ones you're writing yourself. I assume that the objects in the graph each own their links to the other objects, and that the list of objects they link to is publicly available. Since they all descend from a common base class, this shouldn't be difficult to implement there, and you don't need to worry about all the various subclasses.

Assuming the linked objects are available on a public API defined on the base class, it would not be difficult to traverse the graph to look for cycles in the graph; I imagine there's multiple well-known algorithms for finding them (though I admit I haven't looked).

Comment: I'd suggest the [coloring DFS algorithm](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2112/2012sp/lectures/lec24/lec24-12sp.html) for this - it's pretty straightforward and lets you retrieve the cycles you've found for easy debugging (see the *detecting cycles* paragraph inside *topological sorting* although you don't need a full topo sort here it seems).